# Join 4 Decks of cards

Tags: c

I have this code and I intend to create a set of 4 decks, the problem is that in the suits, after the card 51 the result of the division gives 4 and the arrays of the suits do not return the initial position, how can I solve this situation?

Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NCARTAS 52
int main()
{
    const char *numero[]= {"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","V","D","R"};
    const char *naipes[]= {"P","O","C","E"};
    char baralho[208];
    int posNumero,posNaipe;
    for(int i=0; i<208; i++)
    {
        baralho[i]=i;
        posNumero=i%13;
        posNaipe=i/13;

        printf("%s%s \n", numero[posNumero],naipes[posNaipe]);
    }  
}
```

Comment: `char baralho[208];` => `char baralho[NCARTAS*4];` would be cleaner. don't hardcode 208

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, or, arguably, the 4.

Comment: and `for(int i=0; i<208; i++)` => `for(int i=0; i<sizeof(baralho); i++)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
posNaipe = i % NCARTAS / 13;
```

would do it. This is also a touchstone for your knowledge of operator precedence and associativity.